# NodeJS Mock 3rd party service

Tags: node.js, ajax, testing, request

I have an example endpoint, when a request is submitted to it, I do another request to a third party service which turns out to be malfunctional at times. I want to simulate this service being malfunctional so my tests can be relevant.
Here is some example code

```
it('should handle malfunctional 3rd party service', done => {
  Frisby.post(Endpoints.randomEndpoint, {
    email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
  })
  .expect('status', 400)
  .expect('jsonTypes', Common.Types.ErrorModel)
  .done(done);
});
```

On my server side, I have something like..

```
app.post('randomEndpoint', (req, res) => {
  request('http://3rdpaty.com/api')
    .then(data => {
      res.send(200);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send(500);
    })
})
```

My goal is tomock the response from the thrid pary service. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock your http request using [nock library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock)

```
nock('http://3rdpaty.com/')')
 .post('/api/', {
   email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
   firstName: 'John',
   lastName: 'Doe'
 })
 .reply(400, { id: '123ABC' });
```